# How to make a habit in Emacs org-mode that should be performed a set number of times per day

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode you create habits that repeat daily and so on, but I would like to track a task that must be performed three times a day.

```
SCHEDULED: <2019-11-11 Mon .+1d>
```

I am wondering if this can be done with the .+1d syntax as above for the schedule and set it to every 8 hours (which I have not been able to get working), or if this a way to say do this thing three times.

An other solution I thought of which is less satisfying is to encode it as task1, task2 and task3 and set them each to be performed daily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hourly repeat in org-mode, see https://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html

I would advise also to set an hour to start your repetitive task to be able to see it in the "time grid" view (once refreshed) of your agenda.

For example:

```
* TODO Task
    SCHEDULED: <2019-11-12 Tue 6:00 +8h>
```

will show you the "Task" in agenda at 6AM, then at 2PM once the first one marked DONE, etc...

Also for information, https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ is a great ressource for emacs specific questions.